# Как сделать так,чтобы ввод был только одного символа в массив(с клавиатуры)

Tags: java, массивы

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class o30 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = input.nextInt();
        String a[] = new String[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            a[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Я бы использовал класс Char.

```
char mass[] = new char[10];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)
{
    mass[i]  = sc.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while(i < size){
   String s = input.nextLine();
   if(s.length() == 1){
       a[i] = input.nextLine();
       i++;
   }
}
```